# Turning a T1 text-mode character into a maths-mode character

Tags: symbols, characters, font-encodings

I would like to use the T1 font character Ð, `\DH`, as a mathematical symbol, as so in a quick and dirty way I defined

```
\newcommand{\dH}{\text{\DH}}
```

However, in my theorem environments, where the default is italic text, the Ð is italicised, which is not the case for my equation symbols which are standard roman characters. For instance,

```
\begin{lemma}\label{depth_bounds}
The depth function $\dH_{Y'}$ satisfies the inequalities
\[
\dH_{Y'}(x,y) \le lcm(\dH_{G/K}(x),\dH_Y(y))
\]
\end{lemma}
```

The disparity with `\dH_Y` outside the lemma environment, for example, is blatantly obvious:
*Ð*<sub>Y</sub> vs Ð<sub>Y</sub>, modulo HTML spacing issues.

Comment: I should clarify that I want the upright character throughout, i.e. the one outside the lemma environment.

Comment: Adding `\normalfont` in front of `\DH` should solve your problem -- `\newcommand{\dH}{\text{\normalfont\DH}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So for the actually intended way you want to use it, here’s your solution:

```
\newcommand{\dH}{\text{\normalfont\DH}}
```

This should print the `\DH` in “upright character” while the rest of the lemma is italic, as it’s supposed to be.

Comment: Also `\newcommand{\dH}{\textnormal{\DH}}` should work.

Answer (score 3):

I’m not 100% sure whether I got your question right, to be honest, but here is my attempt.

This:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{article} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

\newcommand{\dH}{\text{\DH}}

\begin{document}

\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
Lemma environment:
\begin{lem}\label{depth_bounds}
The depth function $\dH_{Y'}$ satisfies the inequalities
\[
\dH_{Y'}(x,y) \le lcm(\dH_{G/K}(x),\dH_Y(y))
\]
\end{lem}

Equation environment:
\[
\dH_{Y'}(x,y) \le lcm(\dH_{G/K}(x),\dH_Y(y))
\]
\end{document}
```

results in [image: originally posted]

While a small change – namely: `\newcommand{\dH}{\text{\itshape\DH}}`– results in:
[image: small change]

Comment: Ah, I should have said. I want the upright version as default, not the italic version. I tried using `\textrm` but that gave the same result at `\text`